# How to try Translator service on free account of Azure?

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator

Issue: The "Pricing Tier" dropdown is empty due to which the create Translator resource workflow fails as the form validation is unsuccessful.

Background: I am trying Azure for the first time so I have free credit and free testing for 30 days on this account.

What I have tried:

1. I went to create resource and selected "Translator"

[image]

2. I clicked create and then filled in the details but the Pricing Tier dropdown is empty, so I could not select anything:

[image]

3. Next, I clicked on "Review and Create" but it does not create as validation failed:

[image]

Now, I am stuck and don't know how to go forward. Appreciate any help that I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug on our end and we are working to fix it. Meanwhile, as a workaround, can you try changing between subscriptions/regions and the pricing tier should load.